# Disable click event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried unbind, off and nothing seems to work!!

I got an element with a `ID` called: `volume-knob`. I want to disable the click so if i have a button inside the `div` `volume-knob` then the button won't get pressed etc.

I tried the following and the click still works! Please share some light on this nightmare!

```
$('#volume-knob').unbind("click"); //Doesn't work
$(document).unbind("click"); //Trying to disable click on all but still no luck
$('#volume-knob').off("click"); //Doesn't work
```

I then tried adding it on a click event but also no luck:

```
$("#volume-knob").click(function(){
    $('#volume-knob').off("click"); // Still Won't work._.
});
```

What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: How is the event attached in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

You want to prevent the default action of a click event.  Try this.

```
$("#volume-knob").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You need to bind this to the element you don't want clickable, not the parent div.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
$("#volume-knob").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using .on() event handler and have it register with document

```
    $(document).on( "click", "#selector", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

when you register an event on page document it works every time even when there is no selector at the time of function execution but its added later